# Sitecore and broken page editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, sitecore, sitecore7, page-editor

I am having an issue with sitecore, using MVC, where I have this is my page layout file:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><body class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><body class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 10)|!(IE)]><!-->
<body><!--<![endif]-->
```

Page editor is loading into the first "body for ie8" and thus all I see is code and not page editor. Has anyone else experienced this? Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no question here...

Comment: The question was cut off, fixed it.

Comment: In a webforms environment, the Page Editor relies on the outermost FORM tag sitting just inside BODY. If you leave it out, you get a Page Editor experience more or less exactly as you describe here. Not sure how this is handled in MVC, but likely the problem is related.

Answer (score 0):

We are using same approach but for HTML tag instead of BODY without any problems:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced the same the following link helped me..May be you should have a look at it..

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/06/sitecore-page-editor-renders-jumbled-json-as-content.aspx

Comment: plese don't give link as a answer. write the content too.